# Magento 2.1.3 : url_rewrite database table is huge

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.1.3, backup

When trying to install an extension, or performing the average database backup, I've realized i have less then 200 products in my catalog, yet the backup takes FOREVER. In fact, there is a database table 800 megabytes large, while the biggest one after that is only 16 megabytes.

What can i do with this to lighten up my database?
Does this require a fresh new magento installation?

[image: url_rewrite table]

I will also mention that the same database once held 18000+ products.
In there, i currently see [image: current look]

Having nearly 30 links for the one flyer page makes absolutely no sense. Why is magento doing this and how can i fix it?

Is magento creating a store for every store view? because i should have 3 stores (demo 1, demo2 and demo3) with about 8 or 9 languages each... However even with 200 products, the database is still HUGE. There are over 2,200,400 records in the url_rewrite table!

Comment: How many stores and categories do you have?

Comment: i have about 9 stores (one for each language) which i later intend on culling, and i have about 20-30 categories for products.

Comment: From the database table pictured above, it looks like you have about 25 stores, not 9. Having that many stores is going to make the url_rewrite table very large, since you will have a row for each store for each url.

Comment: Thanks dmatthew, updated original post with number of stores, however database size still does not account for the 200 products in my stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this TEMPORARILY with my own set of steps :

0 - Backup code, media, db.

1 - delete the magento stores wich are useless.

2 - delete the store views for each language wich are useless.

3 - check the database table `url_rewrite`, compare with current size of (mine)2200419 rows.

At this point, if the size does not decrease, this points to a problem with the SEO (search engine optimization) system. Use extreme caution when performing next steps :

4 - delete all products

5 - truncate `url_rewrite` and `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` table

6 - save all product categories (`Admin->Products->Categories`)

7 - reimport products (`system->import`)

hope everything works properly and database is smaller.

Unfortunately I haven't found a code-based solution to permanently fix Magento